# What is the gap for the header?

Tags: html, css, styling

I am trying to work out what the X and Y position is for the top left cornor of an element?  For the main-container I believe it to be (8,8) however there is a gap between the maincontainer and header that I am unsure how to calculate this. Does the `<header>` element contain margins or padding within it?

```
header
{
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
}


#main-container
{
     position: absolute;
     top: 8px;
     left: 8px;
     background: #cccccc;
     height: 500px;
     width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Plz add jsfiddle or more html to understand the design of your page.

Comment: each browser can define its own base styles for elements; some browsers may well have default padding or margin for `<header>`

Comment: Have you tried using [reset.css](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
body{
 margin:0;
}
```

Or this *Ugly reset*:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Additionally some older browsers might need the `display:block;` defined for *newer* HTML5 tags (`header, footer, section, article etc...`).

Also, using `top` and `left` properties for `header` is useless
unless you use the `position` property <sup>* Final Demo link</sup>

[Demo with issue](http://jsbin.com/ilacajI/1/edit)  || [Demo without gap](http://jsbin.com/ilacajI/2/edit) || [Final Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilacajI/3/edit)

Comment: I agree on avoiding the asterisk reset. I followed the rule until I found and read this article: http://sixrevisions.com/css/the-history-of-css-resets/ It is a 3-part article that will inform you to allow you to make your OWN decision as to what to reset, and what not to reset.